# Import cookies from firefox to htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want to import cookies from FireFox to HtmlUnit and do some analysis. I've located the firefox cookies file which is called "cookies.sqlite". I've tried to open it with text edit but no luck.

My questions are:

1. Does HtmlUnit support loading cookies from local files?
2. Do FireFox cookies need to be transformed in some way so that HtmlUnit could recognize them?

Comment: `cookies.sqlite` is a database format - see http://www.sqlite.org/ - and there are java bindings available for it (although I haven't had to use any - so can't make any recommendations)